# извлечение 2 short-ов из int

Tags: c

пытаюсь вытащить short-ы из int:

```
int fs = 4489228;
short f1 = *(short*)(&fs);
short f2 = *((short*)(&fs) + 1);
```

получаю  `f1 = -32756 f2 = 68`
но ведь `f1 = 1000000000001100 = -12`. Почему получается `-32756`?

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, `1000000000001100` будет обозначать `-12` в экзотическом [прямом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5) коде (signed magnitude), но его практически никто не использует. Подавляющее большинство современных платформ используют [дополнительный код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5), в котором `1000000000001100` - это именно `-32756`.

Чтобы определить, какому отрицательному значению соответствует представление `1000000000001100` в дополнительном коде надо

1. Инвертировать все биты: `0111111111110011`
2. Прибавить 1 к результату: `0111111111110100`
3. Получили `32756`. Значит исходное представление соответствовало `-32756`.

Во-вторых, язык С не позволяет таким способом "вытащить short-ы из int". Это нарушение правил aliasing. Поведение не определено. Такие трюки делаются через `union` или через `memcpy`, а не через `*(short*) &fs`.

Comment: Людям может быть не очень ясно, что есть `signed magnitude` и `дополнительный код`. По крайне мере оставьте ссылки для изучения вопроса, ибо, как видно, ТС не понимает своей ошибки

Comment: Возможно, стоит добавить и о порядке байт.

Answer (score 4):

Чем не устроили обычные битовые операции?

```
int fs = 4489228;
short f1 = fs & 0xFFFF;
short f2 = fs >> 16;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 4489228;
    /**@@@WARNING@@@ 
    Methods with [&а] -  work with only variable from RAM.
    If [a] is register then use  first or fifth method.
    **/
    //METHOD 1(BEST METHOD)
    {
        short b = a;//or a&0xFFFF
        short c = a>>16;
        printf("a = %d b=%d c=%d \n",a,b,c);
    }
    //METHOD 2
    {
        short b = *((short*)&a); // or *&a;
        short c = *((short *)&a+1);
        printf("a = %d b=%d c=%d \n",a,b,c);
    }
    //METHOD 3
    {
        short b = *(short*)((void*)&a);
        short c = *(short*)((void*)&a+2);
        printf("a = %d b=%d c=%d \n",a,b,c);
    }
    //METHOD 4
    {

        union example
        {
            int int32;
            struct
            {
                short int16_1;
                short int16_2;
            };
        };
        union example e = *(union example *)&a;
        short b =e.int16_1;
        short c =e.int16_2;
        printf("a = %d b=%d c=%d \n",a,b,c);
    }
    //METHOD 5
    {
        union example
        {
            int int32;
            struct
            {
                short int16_1;
                short int16_2;
            };
        };
        union example e = {.int32=a};
        short b =e.int16_1;
        short c =e.int16_2;
        printf("a = %d b=%d c=%d \n",a,b,c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: есть несколько способов кодирования чисел в бинарной системе:

Comment: 1) Direct code. 2) Inverted code. 3) Complementary Code. и так далее. Так в большинство современных платформ используют 3 тип для упрощения деления и вычитания. Есть еще и другие кодировки для специфических вычислительных машин.

Comment: Немного придирок: В 2,3,4 и 5 результат зависит от endianness. 2 и 3 нарушают strict aliasing и вызывают неопределенное поведение. При этом, 3 вообще [не компилируется](https://godbolt.org/g/6qqRzy) (без нестандартных фич компиляторов), потому что стандарт запрещает арифметику с указателями на `void`.

Comment: дорогой друг смотри GAS код который генерирует даный код, а да чтоб уточнить даный код работает на стандарте С17, этот стандарт хорошо интегрирован в компиляторе GCC v.8

Comment: *"работает на стандарте С17"* 3-ий на С17 [не компилируется](https://godbolt.org/g/paq7t7). Если он компилируется у вас, так это скорее всего потому, что в GCC по умолчанию включены нестандартные расширения. *"смотри GAS код"* Нет, я понимаю, что 2 и 3 часто будут работать на практике. Но [*формально*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) так делать нельзя...

Comment: LSB и MSB можно проверить это формальность, для новичков проблема может быть, а если есть страх на указатель на void , используйте указатель на char